# The argument type "User? Function(User)" cant be assign to the parameter type "User? Function(User?)'

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been coding a method that searches for the user. The analyzer shows that the argument type "User? Function(User)" cant be assign to the parameter type "User? Function(User?)'.

What does this error mean? Please tell me what is wrong with this piece of code ?

```
  Stream<User?> get currentUser {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map((User user){
      return user != null ? User.fromFirebase(user, 0) : null;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.map` method here is requiring you to pass a function with has a parameter which is a nullable user (`User?`), and return a nullable user. But you have defined the parameter to be a non-nullable user. Add a `?` to the type of your parameter to make it nullable.

```dart
  Stream<User?> get currentUser {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map((User? user){
      return user != null ? User.fromFirebase(user, 0) : null;
    });
  }
```

Update

I used CLASS User, at the same time I used OBJECT User from Firebase.This led to confusion as I used the same name for two completely different constructs.

```
Stream<Client?> get currentUser {
   return _firebaseAuth
      .authStateChanges()
      .map((User? user) => 
       user != null ? Client.fromFirebase(user) : null);
 }
```

Comment: I tried to solve this way, still the same error (

Comment: The analyzer shows that  the "Argument type "User" Function(User?) (where User is defined in D:\Desktop\flutter\bla-bla-bla) "can't be assigned to the parameter "User Function(User?)"

Comment: Could you include a screenshot?

Comment: Sure 

https://sun9-56.userapi.com/impg/zY0Q_2r5idMO27EYyv3sCEVffgNJnT4mdhkqyg/YYfFmeawFIA.jpg?size=1920x1080&quality=96&sign=849bd8bc67773b94626a99ffdb7b9119&type=album

Comment: don't ask why i painted some places))))

Comment: What does it say exactly where it is cut off? `can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Use...`. If nothing else, you can try to omit the type of your parameter altogether and allow it to use type inference.

Comment: I don’t know how to see the detailed error description also

Comment: I think if you hover over with your mouse it should show full text in a tooltip.

Comment: It shows exactly the same

The argument type “User? Function(User)” cant be assign to the parameter type "User? Function(User?)'

Comment: ? the screenshot shows `The argument type 'User? Function(User?)` not `The argument type 'User? Function(User)`.  If the parameter type (which we cannot see in the screenshot) is also `User? Function(User?)` then they should match.

Comment: Can you try removing the type of the parameter altogether `(user) { ... }` instead of `(User? user) { ... }`. This should automatically decide a type for the parameter due to type inference.

Comment: If you mouse hover over `user` it should tell you what the type was inferenced as.

Comment: It sounds like the code you posted in the description was correct then? I'm honestly still confused by this.

Comment: No it wasn't correct. I just solved this problem, everything is much more trivial. It turns out I had a User class whose name is identical to the Firebase object User. This is where the problems come from.

Comment: Well, that would explain it.